# Retain sent to deallocated UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have an issue when I pop a VC off the navigation controller and simulate a memory warning, the app will crash.  NSZombies shows me which vc it is, but the funny thing is, it happens with a vanilla UIViewController with no code.

Here is my push code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:     

    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.testVc = [[ZTestVCViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.testVc animated:YES];
}
```

Here is what happens when I simulate a memory warning:

```
2014-12-23 20:28:12.776 ----[3518:78070] Received memory warning.
2014-12-23 20:28:12.778 ----[3518:78070] *** -[ZTestVCViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Can't figure this out for the life of me.

I've scoured through other SO posts but nothing seems similar because this is happen with a vanilla vc with no dangling pointers.

EDIT:

Would like to add that I am using ARC and self.testVc is a weak reference.  Using a strong reference is out of the question because that memory would just hang around.

Comment: Did you implemented `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method ?

Comment: Confirm `self.testVc` is `weak` reference instead of `Strong`

Comment: Yes, `self.testVc` is a weak reference.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you are popping from viewController B to A., then make sure that you did not release any IBOutlet of B view controller before dealloc method.